# Expression parameter reference

Tags: c#, lambda, syntax, expression

I've created a download manager, but as far as download manager stores the download arguments, it's working good.

```
        Downloader downloader = new Downloader();
        downloader.Add(new List<Query>(){
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_pozycje, () => dataset.PobierzTransSprzedazPozycja(downloader.Filter)),
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_rabaty_dodatkowe, () => dataset.PobierzDokumentySprzedazyRabaty(downloader.Filter)),
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_teksty, () => dataset.PobierzDokumentySprzedazyTeksty(downloader.Filter))
                            });
```

But in some cases I need my queries to store the arguments, so it should look like:

```
        Downloader downloader = new Downloader();
        downloader.Add(new List<Query>(){
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_pozycje, () => dataset.PobierzTransSprzedazPozycja(query.Filter)),
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_rabaty_dodatkowe, () => dataset.PobierzDokumentySprzedazyRabaty(query.Filter)),
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_teksty, () => dataset.PobierzDokumentySprzedazyTeksty(query.Filter))
                            });
```

Note that in first code snippet I use downloader.Filter, in second I use (fabricated) query.Filter

I know that I can make constructions like:

```
        var query = new Query(dsSprzedaz.trans_sprzedaz_pozycje);
        query.AddFunc(() => dsSprzedaz.PobierzTransSprzedazPozycja(query.Filter));
```

But adding 20-30 queries like this would be terrible.

I tried sollution like this:

```
            Filter filter;
            new Query(dsSprzedaz.trans_sprzedaz_pozycje,() => dsSprzedaz.PobierzTransSprzedazPozycja(filter), out filter),
```

but it copy value from query.Filter, not the reference.

//EDIT

Here's the most important code of downloader:

```
    private Task Execute()
    {
        var Tasks = new List<Task>(Queries.Count);

        foreach (var query in Queries)
        {
            var task = query.Execute(CancellationToken);
            Tasks.Add(task);
        }

        return Task.WhenAll(Tasks);
    }

    private void CreateFilter(List<long> id_list)
    {
        lock (Data)
        {
            Data.Clear();

            Data.Append("(0");

            foreach (var value in id_list)
                Data.Append("," + value);

            Data.Append(")");
        }
    }

    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return Data.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And Query:

```
public class Query
{
    DataTable Source;
    Func<DataTable> Download;
    StringBuilder Data;

    public Query(DataTable Source, Expression<Func<DataTable>> Download, out string filter)
    {
        this.Source = Source;
        this.Data = new StringBuilder();

        filter = Filter;
        this.Download = Download.Compile();
    }

    public async Task Execute(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable result = await Task.Run(() => Download());

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;

            Source.Merge(result);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private void CreateFilter(List<long> id_list)
    {
        lock (Data)
        {
            Data.Clear();

            Data.Append("(0");

            foreach (var value in id_list)
                Data.Append("," + value);

            Data.Append(")");
        }
    }

    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return Data.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Hi @wiktorowski211, Welcome! You question is not clear. I don't see any difference between the first snippet of code and the second. And It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and what is wrong now. Try to edit the post and make it more clear so everybody can understand and help you

Comment: Note that in first code snippet I use downloader.Filter, in second I use (fabricated) query.Filter

Comment: No, Not seeing that. any way, still it's not clear. not to me at least

Comment: Arguments of the function inside lambda expressions

Comment: Maybe it is not how you store Filter, but how you use it. Could you post `Query` source and how you use queries from `Downloader`?

Comment: I've posted source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make Query store information if it should use it's own filter (you said that you want to use it's filter only some times, in other cases you want to use Downloader.Filter)

   ```
   public class Query
   {
       DataTable Source;
       Func<string, DataTable> Download;
       StringBuilder Data;
       public bool IsOwnFilter { get; set; }

       public Query(DataTable Source, Func<string, DataTable> Download, bool isOwnFilter = false)
       {
           this.Source = Source;
           this.Data = new StringBuilder();
           this.Download = Download;
           this.IsOwnFilter = isOwnFilter;
       }

       public async Task Execute(strign filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           try
           {
               DataTable result = await Task.Run(() => Download(filter));
               if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;
               Source.Merge(result);
           }
           catch (Exception) { }
       }
       // This is not used in your code
       private void CreateFilter(List<long> id_list)
       {
           lock (Data)
           {
               Data.Clear();
               Data.Append("(0");
               foreach (var value in id_list)
                   Data.Append("," + value);

               Data.Append(")");
           }
       }

       public string Filter
       {
           get
           {
               return Data.ToString();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Next when you call it from Downloader, check for new flag and pass correct filter:

   ```
   private Task Execute()
   {
       var Tasks = new List<Task>(Queries.Count);

       foreach (var query in Queries)
       {
           // call Execute with Query filter or Downloader.Filter
           var task = query.Execute(query.IsOwnFilter ? query.Filter : Filter, CancellationToken);
           Tasks.Add(task);
       }

       return Task.WhenAll(Tasks);
   }
   ```

And when you add queries to Downloader:

```
Downloader downloader = new Downloader();
        downloader.Add(new List<Query>(){
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_pozycje, (filter) => dataset.PobierzTransSprzedazPozycja(filter)),
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_rabaty_dodatkowe, (filter) => dataset.PobierzDokumentySprzedazyRabaty(filter)),
                            new Query(dataset.trans_sprzedaz_teksty, (filter) => dataset.PobierzDokumentySprzedazyTeksty(filter))
                            });
```